# Script for projector turn on.

Tags: projector

Not sure if this the right place, but I was tasked with creating a script for which would be able to turn our networked projectors on and off (which can already be turned on and off through the web interface.) The projector model is Christie DWU-675e. I was just wondering if this was possible and if so,  what would be the best method to go about doing it?

Comment: This seems more like a programming question, but the general answer is: it's almost certainly possible. If it's being done through a web interface then it can likely be done from any app that can host a socket. One issue is whether the commands and responses are documented anywhere, or whether you have to sniff them out yourself.

Comment: You might be better asking on SuperUser.

Comment: What OSes do you have available? Does the webUI need any form of authentication/